# Error getting information from address book

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, cocoa

I'm having an issue retrieving an array of certain data from the address book.  Here's the code:

```
- (void) getContacts{    
    ABAddressBookRef ab = ABAddressBookCreate();
    NSMutableArray *retVal = (__bridge NSMutableArray *)(ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(ab));
    CFRelease(ab);

    contact* temp=[[contact alloc] init];
    NSMutableArray* tempArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    for(int i=0;i<[retVal count];i++)
        [tempArray insertObject:
          [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",
            [temp set2:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",
              [[retVal objectAtIndex:i] kABPersonFirstNameProperty]] 
                  last:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",
                    [[retVal objectAtIndex:i] kABPersonLastNameProperty]] 
                number:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",
                  [[retVal objectAtIndex:i] kABPersonPhoneProperty]]]] atIndex:i];

    _objects=tempArray;

    [self alert:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",_objects] title:@"TEMP"];
}
```

The errors I'm getting are about the kABPerson properties.

Some more clarification: essentially I'm grabbing all the data from the address book into the first array and then I'm manually going through that array and attempting to retrieve the data that I need for the rest of my app.

Any ideas?

```
Just for more clarification here's my contact.h file:

@interface contact : NSString{
    NSString* first;
    NSString* last;
    NSString* number;
}
@end
```

And here's my contact.m file:

```
@implementation contact

- (void) set:(NSString*)first2 last:(NSString*)last2 number:(NSString*)number2{
    first=first2;
    last=last2;
    number=number2;
}

- (contact*) set2:(NSString*)first2 last:(NSString*)last2 number:(NSString*)number2{
    first=first2;
    last=last2;
    number=number2;

    return self;
}

@end
```

Here's that line that seems to be too long to post:

```
//Enter contact into tempArray
    [tempArray insertObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[temp set:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",(__bridge NSString *)(ABRecordCopyValue((__bridge ABMultiValueRef)[retVal objectAtIndex:i],kABPersonFirstNameProperty))] last:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",(__bridge NSString *)(ABRecordCopyValue((__bridge ABMultiValueRef)[retVal objectAtIndex:i],kABPersonLastNameProperty))] number:(__bridge NSString *)ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex((__bridge ABMultiValueRef)((__bridge NSString*)ABRecordCopyValue((__bridge ABRecordRef)([retVal objectAtIndex:i]),kABPersonPhoneProperty)), 0)]] atIndex:i];
```

Comment: You should say what the actual errors are.

Comment: True that, sorry.

1) no visible @interface for 'contact' declareds the selector... meaning it doesn't know what that method is

2)no known instance method for selector kAB...

Comment: That should be declares by the way...

Comment: I fixed the first error:

[tempArray insertObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[contact set2:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[retVal objectAtIndex:i] kABPersonFirstNameProperty]] last2:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[retVal objectAtIndex:i] kABPersonLastNameProperty]] number2:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[retVal objectAtIndex:i] kABPersonPhoneProperty]]]] atIndex:i];

Answer (score 0):

`kABPersonFirstNameProperty` is a property **ID**, not an Objective-C object property.

That is, you can't use `[[retVal objectAtIndex:i] kABPersonFirstNameProperty]` -- you will instead need to access the first and last names like this:

```
CFStringRef firstName = ABRecordCopyValue ([retVal objectAtIndex:i], kABPersonFirstNameProperty);
CFStringRef lastName = ABRecordCopyValue ([retVal objectAtIndex:i], kABPersonLastNameProperty);
CFStringRef phoneNum = ABRecordCopyValue ([retVal objectAtIndex:i], kABPersonPhoneProperty);
```

Then don't forget that ABRecordCopyValue follows the Create Rule -- you'll need to `CFRelease(firstName)` afterwards.

Comment: @brian  yes I actually did notice that after a few hours of playing about with it.  I haven't checked the boards for a few days now.

I got the previous erros taken care of, but now I'm getting a memory error for some reason in this line:

Comment: What that line should be doing is picking out the mobile number alone without the multivalue return